# Computation of a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=(l_1,\cdots,l_n)\in\mathbb C^n$ non zero. Define a matrix $M\in\mathcal M_n(\mathbb C[X])$ by $M=\begin{pmatrix}X&1&0&\cdots&0\\0&X&1&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\&&\ddots&\ddots&1\\0&\cdots&&0&X\end{pmatrix}$. The question: determine $D_n=\det(M^iV)$ ($0\le i<n)$. Thanks in advance. Tries with $n=2$ and $n=3$ lead to think that $D_n\in\mathbb C$ instead of $\mathbb C[X]$. One can conjecture that $D_n=(-1)^nl^n_n$.

Comment: $M^iV$ is a vector, therefore it has no determinant. Also, $M\in \Bbb C[X]$?! Don't you mean $(\Bbb C[X])^{n\times n}$

Comment: You put the $n$ vectors in a table, then you can compute the determinant. That's a way to check the dependance of vectors

Comment: I see **one** vector called $V$ which is, as you say, an element of $\Bbb C^n$.

Comment: @Gae.S.There are $n$ vectors: $M^iV$ for $i=0,\ldots,n-1$.

Comment: Propably he means the determinant of the matrix constructed by those vectors...

Comment: dmitry> Yes!! I mean that.

Comment: Ah, ok I see now. Sorry I got confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $M=XI+J$, where $J$ is the $n\times n$ nilpotent Jordan block. By using elementary column operations, we get
\begin{aligned}
&\det\pmatrix{v&Mv&M^2v&M^3v&\cdots&M^{n-2}v&M^{n-1}v}\\
&=\det\pmatrix{v&Jv+Xv&M^2v&M^3v&\cdots&M^{n-2}v&M^{n-1}v}\\
&=\det\pmatrix{v&Jv&M^2v&M^3v&\cdots&M^{n-2}v&M^{n-1}v}\\
&=\det\pmatrix{v&Jv&J^2v+2XJv+X^2v&M^3v&\cdots&M^{n-2}v&M^{n-1}v}\\
&=\det\pmatrix{v&Jv&J^2v&M^3v&\cdots&M^{n-2}v&M^{n-1}v}\\
&\cdots\\
&=\det\pmatrix{v&Jv&J^2v&J^3v&\cdots&J^{n-2}v&J^{n-1}v}=:\det(A).
\end{aligned}
$A=\pmatrix{v&Jv&J^2v&J^3v&\cdots&J^{n-2}v&J^{n-1}v}$ is a matrix whose entries on the main anti-diagonal are all equal to $l_n$ and whose entries below the main anti-diagonal are all equal to zero. Therefore $\det(A)=(-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}l_n^n$.